# Using "if" for string and using " bitwise AND" or " logical AND"

Tags: python, numpy

I want to check if the string in the second column of my dataset is disk , tabel or any other thing.

This is some sample of dataset with name X:

```
16  disk    11  10.29   4.63    30.22 
79  table   11  20.49   60.60   20.22 
17  disk    11  22.17   0.71    10.37
```

I used the following code:

```
def featureMaking(X):

   if  (X[1]=='disk'):            
       print('It is in disk group')
   elif np.logical_or(X[1]=='table', X[1]=='chair'):
       print('table or chair')
   else: 
       print('others')
```

The error is:

```
 ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I changed elif np.logical_or(X[1]=='table', X[1]=='chair'): to  elif (X[1]=='table' || X[1]=='chair'): but error exists. Could you please guide me to solve the problem?

And also even when i ignore the eflif and i change the code to :

```
def featureMaking(X):

if  (X[1]=='disk'):            
     print('It is in disk group')

else: 
    print('others')
```

But yet i have the same error!!!

Comment: What exactly is `X`? A list? A pandas DataFrame? A numpy array?

Comment: X is name of dataset which is a numpy.ndarray

Comment: What is `X.shape` and `X.dtype`?

Comment: >>> X.shape
(4857, 6)
>>> type(X)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>   >>> X.dtype
dtype('O')

Comment: Could you check what is the type of X[1]? (print type(X[1]))

Comment: >>> print type(X[1])
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: See. Here is the problem. You are comparing numpy.ndarray with string. Check what type X[0][1] or X[1][1] is. In your if statement, you should be checking X[0][1] or X[i][1] with 'disk'

Comment: Ohhh, the problem is in that i have to write X[1][1]  as u wrote here! and i think X[1] doesn't have meaning! and for checking all i think i have to use for loop and then X[i,1] in if. thanksss

Comment: @Talia: Exactly. :)
Usually, in these type of issues, you should print the value of the variable and it's type. Comes in very handy :)

Comment: There's almost never a good reason to use `np.ndarray`s with the `object` dtype - by treating each element as an arbitrary Python object you lose out on the performance benefits of numpy. It's much better practice to use a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) or something like [a pandas DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) to represent data with heterogeneous types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`X[1]` is the second row of your two dimensional `numpy.ndarray` `X`. If you want the second column of the second row, access it as `X[1,1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
>>> a
array([['16', 'disk', '11', '10.29', '4.63', '30.22'],
       ['79', 'table', '11', '20.49', '60.60', '20.22'],
       ['17', 'disk', '11', '22.17', '0.71', '10.37']], 
      dtype='|S5')
```

You can use `np.where`:

```
>>> rows, cols=np.where(a=='disk')
>>> a[rows]
array([['16', 'disk', '11', '10.29', '4.63', '30.22'],
       ['17', 'disk', '11', '22.17', '0.71', '10.37']], 
      dtype='|S5')
```

Or:

```
>>> rows, cols=np.where(a=='table')
>>> a[rows]
array([['79', 'table', '11', '20.49', '60.60', '20.22']], 
      dtype='|S5')
```